# Determine when Relay has fetched data and populated props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, relay

When I call **this.props.relay.setVariables**, Relay will fetch data given these new variables, and afterwards I want to do stuff with this data. However I cannot figure out a good way to know exactly when this occur.
I first tried using the **onReadyStateChange** callback on **setVariables** but this didn't catch the moment when props was populated.

What I ended up doing to fix the problem was using a **setTimeout** in **componentWillRecieveProps** and by then the props is populated with the new data. But is there a better way to determine when data has been fetched?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to invoke `setTimeout` inside of `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` as the lifecycle method gets called automatically once the component's props change so you just need a conditional block like this in the `componentWillReceiveProps` (assuming the variables can be distinguished via `===` check)

```
if(this.props.data !== nextProps.data){
//do your stuff
}
```

or you could use the `length` field if the `data` is an array:

```
if(this.props.data.length !== nextProps.data.length){
//do your stuff
}
```

If the condition holds, it means that you've received the new data you were looking for and you can process it.